# Delete an element in a set by name

Tags: scala, set, element

I have the following set:

```
class Element (var Name:String, var Description: String)

var MoreElement: Set[Element] = Set(E1, E2, E3, ...)
```

How do I delete an Element in a set MoreElement by name.

I found this solution:

```
MoreElement -= (MoreElement find (_.Name == "nameOfElementToRemove")).get
```

but I would not use the get, because if you does not find the item is thrown an exception, however I do not want no exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MoreElement = MoreElement filterNot (_.Name == "nameOfElementToRemove")
```

Answer (score 6):

The direct answer to you question is to use filter, meaning something like:

```
moreElements = moreElements.filter( _.name != "nameOfElementToRemove")
```

Note this will scan the set. If you want a set indexed by name, you should really use a Map.

However, some caveats:

A set is a collection of unique elements. In order to compare elements in the set, it uses the contained type's equality operator. In your case, the Element class needs to define the 'equals' method (and hashCode) so the set can effectively compare instances.

In addition, you need to keep in mind that Set is an immutable class in Scala, so in your example you're really creating a new set, despite using an operator that appears to modify the existing set.

If you want a mutable set, you need to import scala.collection.mutable.Set.

Comment: I can do that too
    moreElements = moreElements.filterNot( _.name ==    "nameOfElementToRemove")